# How do you benchmark an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I am trying to run a test of the speed of an Arduino, and how it's affected by different temperatures. Does the following code assess this properly?

```
long num = 0;
long startTime = 0;
long endTime = 0;
int duration = 0;
String buffer;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  startTime = millis();
  benchmark();
  endTime = millis();
  duration = endTime - startTime;
  Serial.print(startTime);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(endTime);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(duration); 
}

void benchmark() {
  num = 0;
  for(num = 0; num < 1000000; num++);
}
```

I'm using an Uno, if that matters.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're doing this?

Comment: I have an idea. An Arduino with GPS and real time clock, using this https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10710 . I'd replace for millis.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping. I will post my results when the trials are completed.

Answer (score 2):

No.

That is because millis will be equally affected by any frequency change (due to temperature) as the benchmark code. You would need an external clock source that is precise enough.

Note that temperature doesn't have that big an impact on crystal oscillators. Somewhere around 10ppm between -20 and +20 degrees C. The crystal itself is probably already 50ppm precision to start with (higher precision ones are more expensive).

Comment: Would it work to use a serial output to a PC, and having it measure the interval?

Comment: Maybe. But how precise is you PCs clock? How does Serial.print() affect your benchmark? What is the latency of the serial connection (I don't think you have a realtime OS)?

Comment: It doesn't have to include Serial. I'd just like to know how fast the Arduino is running, so I can determine the difference temperature makes.

Comment: 20ppm is only a 0.002% difference. You'd need some pretty precise instruments to measure this tiny difference.

Comment: Ah, I see. I only need to be precise enough to see there is no large difference.

Comment: "Large" is relative. 20ppm is about 10.5 minutes over an entire year.

Comment: But then you'd have to have a constant temperature during this entire period :-)
What is it you want to achieve with the results? You can just look at the datasheet of the crystal to get an idea of what the difference would be.

Comment: I really just want to measure real world performance.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, you cannot measure the stability of a device using routines that themselves depend on the device clock.

To do this properly you need an external measuring device that has a clock source at least 10 times more stable than the Arduino xtal. Most frequency counters would qualify.
Just set up a timer to provide a constant output frequency, and attach the counter to the pin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, compiler will just remove your loop, unless you disable compiler optimization, witch will invalidate your test.
Also don't worry about clock drift; as clock also run instruction, a faster clock will also mean a faster instruction cicle, so in the end if you calculate instruction/s the value will be valid.

Also serial communication slowness is not a problem as you calculate the value BEFORE sending anything.

Now, exactly what you want benchmark? In your case, you should put some instruction the for, like a variable++, and then print that sum (if you don't use it, again compiler will optimize all away)

But the you are bancharking for and ++. You may use a NOP() instruction, and then a float, a bitshift, a function call, and so on; you will find very different result, sometimes, sometimes compilator will trick your code.

Then when you'll have banchamark, against what will you compare your result?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not going to compare it to another device, but instead just graph speed vs ambient temperature.

Comment: Whoa missed that. Basically you want measure the clock drift, witch means you need to find a more precise clock. As far as i know there are very expansive thermo compensated clock. Pc clock may drift lot, they need to output fast clock, its stability may have relatively great error